# Play background music in all activities of Android app

Tags: android, background, playback

I spend about 20 hours until now and my problem there still is .
I am creating an android application that has several Activities (mainMenu , aboutUs,setting).
I followed the best answered of below link and that was O.K . 
[Music played using asyncTask isn't stopping by using cancel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22541751/music-played-using-asynctask-isnt-stopping-by-using-cancel)

When i run my app,(my code is in mainActivity ), the music begin and it does not stop when navigate to other Activities . This is GOOD .
But i put a **ToggleButton** in my setting_activity Activity that i hope this Button starts and stops this music. NOW my question is how can i stop and/or start music again from setting_activity ?

in another solution :
I create a class MusicManager and i call it`s start and stop . 
But this was several problems too :

1. Music started in mainMenu_activity but only play for about 15 seconds and then stopped.
2. I could not stop the music from another activities.At this time i play music in mainMenua_ctivity as this line codes :

   ```
   MusicManager mm = new MusicManager(this, R.raw.background_sound);
   mm.play();
   ```

How can i stop playing that ?
 3. The music stopped when i navigate to other activities .

```
public class MusicManager implements OnPreparedListener {

    static MediaPlayer mPlayer;
    Context context;
    private int mySoundId;

    public MusicManager(Context ctx, int musicID) {
        context = ctx;
        mySoundId = musicID;
        mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, mySoundId);
        mPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
    }

    public void play() {
        mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, mySoundId);

    }

    public void stop() {
        mPlayer.stop();
        mPlayer.release();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer player) {
        player.start();
        mPlayer.setLooping(true);
        mPlayer.setVolume(25, 25);

    }

}
```

Finally i want to play a background music in all activities without stop/start music .
How can i do it ?

Answer (score 10):

You could put the music player in a service. This would make it independent from the Activities and you would still be able to control the playback through intents.

Here are some code example about it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8209975/2804473
The code below is written by Synxmax here at StackOverflow, and covered in the link above:

```
public class BackgroundSoundService extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = null;
    MediaPlayer player;
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {

        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.idil);
        player.setLooping(true); // Set looping
        player.setVolume(100,100);

    }
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        player.start();
        return 1;
    }

    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        // TO DO
    }
    public IBinder onUnBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TO DO Auto-generated method
        return null;
    }

    public void onStop() {

    }
    public void onPause() {

    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        player.stop();
        player.release();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {

    }
}
```

Comment: I created a class same as above and in main_activity class in the onCreate() i wrote Intent svc = new Intent(this, BackgroundSoundService.class);
startService(svc);  , but my music did not play .

Comment: @saeid112 Take a look here as well http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/258176/Adding-Background-Music-to-Android-App

Comment: really stuck in this! unbelievable that a service cant be controlled from other activity.

Comment: Take a look at Otto by Jake Wharton. If you absolutely have to, you could use it to control the service through it sounds more like you should reconsider your design instead.

Comment: @SimonCedergrenMalmqvist : how to access methods of service from activity ? Please help for this

Comment: @anand why do you want to access service methods from activity? That's not possible. I think you are trying to start/stop song from activity. In that case, you should use intents and handle them.

Comment: Android documentation advises against creating a service for this scenario: "If you must perform work outside of your main thread, but only while the user is interacting with your application, you should instead create a new thread in the context of another application component. For example, if you want to play some music, but only while your activity is running, you might create a thread in onCreate(), start running it in onStart(), and stop it in onStop()." https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services#Choosing-service-thread

Answer (score 2):

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate (){
      super.onCreate();

       Player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.jingle);
       mPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);

       if(mPlayer!= null)
        {
            mPlayer.setLooping(true);
            mPlayer.setVolume(100,100);
        }


        mPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {

      public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int
          extra){

            onError(mPlayer, what, extra);
            return true;
        }
          });
    }
```

Comment: While this code might answer the question you still might consider adding a few explanatory sentences as this increases the value of your answer for other users.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class serv extends Service{

    MediaPlayer mp;
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
    public void onCreate()
    {   
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.b);
        mp.setLooping(false);
    }
    public void onDestroy()
    {       
        mp.stop();
    }
    public void onStart(Intent intent,int startid){

        Log.d(tag, "On start");
        mp.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The top answer is correct, however you have to add the service to the manifest file.

```
 <service android:enabled="true" android:name="BackgroundSoundService" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Simon's answer above is correct. I had similar problem where I have fragments which had music player and I needed to go back to that UI on click of a button. Your case is similar but instead of going back to UI, you want to control playback. Here is what I did for my application. This takes care of playback of audio list including shuffle and repeat functionality. This takes care of showing media controls in notification bar too.

> 1. Create a service `MusicPlayerService` with following code:

```
public class MediaPlayerService extends Service implements MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener,
            MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener, MediaPlayer.OnSeekCompleteListener,
            MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener, MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener,
    
            AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener {
            
            
        public static final String ACTION_PLAY = "pkg_name.ACTION_PLAY";
        public static final String ACTION_PAUSE = "pkg_name.ACTION_PAUSE";
        public static final String ACTION_PREVIOUS = "pkg_name.ACTION_PREVIOUS";
        public static final String ACTION_NEXT = "pkg_name.ACTION_NEXT";
        public static final String ACTION_STOP = "pkg_name.ACTION_STOP";
    
        private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    
        //MediaSession
        private MediaSessionManager mediaSessionManager;
        private MediaSessionCompat mediaSession;
        private MediaControllerCompat.TransportControls transportControls;
    
        //AudioPlayer notification ID
        private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 101;
    
        //Used to pause/resume MediaPlayer
        private int resumePosition;
    
        // Binder given to clients
        private final IBinder iBinder = new LocalBinder();
    
        //List of available Audio files
        private ArrayList<PlayableTrack> audioList;
        private int audioIndex = -1;
    
    
        //Handle incoming phone calls
        private boolean ongoingCall = false;
        private PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener;
        private TelephonyManager telephonyManager;
        private Bitmap albumArtBitmap;
        private boolean shuffle = false;
        private boolean repeat = false;
        private Random rand;
    
        /**
         * Service lifecycle methods
         */
        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            return iBinder;
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
            // Perform one-time setup procedures
    
            // Manage incoming phone calls during playback.
            // Pause MediaPlayer on incoming call,
            // Resume on hangup.
            callStateListener();
            //ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY -- change in audio outputs -- BroadcastReceiver
            registerBecomingNoisyReceiver();
            //Listen for new Audio to play -- BroadcastReceiver
            register_playNewAudio();
            rand = new Random();
            StorageUtil storage = new StorageUtil(getApplicationContext());
            shuffle = storage.loadShuffleRepeat("Shuffle");
            repeat = storage.loadShuffleRepeat("Repeat");
        }
    
        //The system calls this method when an activity, requests the service be started
        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            try {
    
                //Load data from SharedPreferences
                StorageUtil storage = new StorageUtil(getApplicationContext());
                audioList = storage.loadAudio();
                audioIndex = storage.loadAudioIndex();
    
                if (audioIndex != -1 && audioIndex < audioList.size()) {
                    //index is in a valid range
                    activeAudio = audioList.get(audioIndex);
                } else {
                    stopSelf();
                }
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                stopSelf();
            }
    
            if (mediaSessionManager == null) {
                try {
                    initMediaSession();
                    initMediaPlayer();
                } catch (RemoteException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    stopSelf();
                }
                buildNotification(PlaybackStatus.PLAYING);
            }
    
            //Handle Intent action from MediaSession.TransportControls
            handleIncomingActions(intent);
            return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        }
    
        @Override
        public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
            mediaSession.release();
            removeNotification();
            return super.onUnbind(intent);
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                stopMedia();
                mediaPlayer.reset();
            }
            //Disable the PhoneStateListener
            if (phoneStateListener != null) {
                telephonyManager.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
            }
    
            removeNotification();
    
            //unregister BroadcastReceivers
            unregisterReceiver(becomingNoisyReceiver);
            unregisterReceiver(playNewAudio);
    
            Picasso.get().cancelRequest(target);
        }
    
        /**
         * Service Binder
         */
        public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
            public MediaPlayerService getService() {
                // Return this instance of LocalService so clients can call public methods
                return MediaPlayerService.this;
            }
        }
    
    
        /**
         * MediaPlayer callback methods
         */
        @Override
        public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
            //Invoked indicating buffering status of
            //a media resource being streamed over the network.
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            //Invoked when playback of a media source has completed.
            stopMedia();
        }
    
        @Override
        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
            //Invoked when there has been an error during an asynchronous operation
            switch (what) {
                case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_NOT_VALID_FOR_PROGRESSIVE_PLAYBACK:
                    Log.d("MediaPlayer Error", "MEDIA ERROR NOT VALID FOR PROGRESSIVE PLAYBACK " + extra);
                    break;
                case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_SERVER_DIED:
                    Log.d("MediaPlayer Error", "MEDIA ERROR SERVER DIED " + extra);
                    break;
                case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN:
                    Log.d("MediaPlayer Error", "MEDIA ERROR UNKNOWN " + extra);
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            //Invoked when the media source is ready for playback.
            playMedia();
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusState) {
    
            //Invoked when the audio focus of the system is updated.
            switch (focusState) {
                case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN:
                    // resume playback
                    if (mediaPlayer == null) initMediaPlayer();
                    else if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) mediaPlayer.start();
                    mediaPlayer.setVolume(1.0f, 1.0f);
                    break;
                case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS:
                    // Lost focus for an unbounded amount of time: stop playback and release media player
                    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) mediaPlayer.stop();
                    mediaPlayer.reset();
                    mediaPlayer = null;
                    break;
                case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT:
                    // Lost focus for a short time, but we have to stop
                    // playback. We don't release the media player because playback
                    // is likely to resume
                    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) mediaPlayer.pause();
                    break;
                case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK:
                    // Lost focus for a short time, but it's ok to keep playing
                    // at an attenuated level
                    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) mediaPlayer.setVolume(0.1f, 0.1f);
                    break;
            }
        }
    
        /**
         * MediaPlayer actions
         */
        private void initMediaPlayer() {
            if (mediaPlayer == null)
                mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();//new MediaPlayer instance
    
            //Set up MediaPlayer event listeners
            mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
            mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
            mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
            mediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
            mediaPlayer.setOnSeekCompleteListener(this);
            mediaPlayer.setOnInfoListener(this);
            //Reset so that the MediaPlayer is not pointing to another data source
            mediaPlayer.reset();
    
            mediaPlayer.setAudioAttributes(new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                    .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
                    .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
                    .build());
            try {
                // Set the data source to the mediaFile location
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(activeAudio.getFileLocation());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                stopSelf();
            }
            mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
        }
    
        public void playMedia() {
            if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
            buildNotification(PlaybackStatus.PLAYING);
            Intent intent = new Intent("PLAYBACK_STARTED");
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
        }
    
        private void stopMedia() {
            if (mediaPlayer == null) return;
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mediaPlayer.stop();
            }
        }
    
        public void pauseMedia() {
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mediaPlayer.pause();
                resumePosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
            }
            buildNotification(PlaybackStatus.PAUSED);
            Intent intent = new Intent("PLAYBACK_PAUSED");
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
        }
    
        private void resumeMedia() {
            if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mediaPlayer.seekTo(resumePosition);
                mediaPlayer.start();
                buildNotification(PlaybackStatus.PLAYING);
                Intent intent = new Intent("PLAYBACK_STARTED");
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
            }
        }
    
        /**
         * ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY -- change in audio outputs
         */
        private BroadcastReceiver becomingNoisyReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                //pause audio on ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY
                pauseMedia();
                buildNotification(PlaybackStatus.PAUSED);
            }
        };
    
        private void registerBecomingNoisyReceiver() {
            //register after getting audio focus
            IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(AudioManager.ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY);
            registerReceiver(becomingNoisyReceiver, intentFilter);
        }
    
        /**
         * Handle PhoneState changes
         */
        private void callStateListener() {
            // Get the telephony manager
            telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            //Starting listening for PhoneState changes
            phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
                    switch (state) {
                        //if at least one call exists or the phone is ringing
                        //pause the MediaPlayer
                        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                            if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                                pauseMedia();
                                ongoingCall = true;
                            }
                            break;
                        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                            // Phone idle. Start playing.
                            if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                                if (ongoingCall) {
                                    ongoingCall = false;
                                    resumeMedia();
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }
            };
            // Register the listener with the telephony manager
            // Listen for changes to the device call state.
            telephonyManager.listen(phoneStateListener,
                    PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
        }
            
        /**
         * MediaSession and Notification actions
         */
        private void initMediaSession() throws RemoteException {
            if (mediaSessionManager != null) return; //mediaSessionManager exists
    
            mediaSessionManager = (MediaSessionManager) getSystemService(Context.MEDIA_SESSION_SERVICE);
            // Create a new MediaSession
            mediaSession = new MediaSessionCompat(getApplicationContext(), "AudioPlayer");
            //Get MediaSessions transport controls
            transportControls = mediaSession.getController().getTransportControls();
            //set MediaSession -> ready to receive media commands
            mediaSession.setActive(true);
            //indicate that the MediaSession handles transport control commands
            // through its MediaSessionCompat.Callback.
            mediaSession.setFlags(MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_TRANSPORT_CONTROLS);
    
            //Set mediaSession's MetaData
            updateMetaData();
    
            // Attach Callback to receive MediaSession updates
            mediaSession.setCallback(new MediaSessionCompat.Callback() {
                // Implement callbacks
                @Override
                public void onPlay() {
                    super.onPlay();
                    resumeMedia();
                }
    
                @Override
                public void onPause() {
                    super.onPause();
                    pauseMedia();
                }
            });
        }
            
        private void updateMetaData() {
            fetchBitmapOfAlbum();
            // Update the current metadata
            mediaSession.setMetadata(new MediaMetadataCompat.Builder()
                    .putBitmap(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM_ART, albumArtBitmap)
                    .putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST, "")
                    .putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM, activeAudio.getAlbumName())
                    .putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_TITLE, activeAudio.getTrackName())
                    .build());
        }
    
        private Target target = new Target() {
            @Override
            public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                albumArtBitmap = bitmap;
            }
    
            @Override
            public void onBitmapFailed(Exception e, Drawable errorDrawable) {
    
            }
    
            @Override
            public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
            }
        };
    
        private void fetchBitmapOfAlbum() {
            Picasso.get().load(activeAudio.getAlbumArt())
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.rotate_animation)
                    .error(R.drawable.ic_blank)
                    .into(target);
        }
        
        private void buildNotification(PlaybackStatus playbackStatus) {
           
            int notificationAction = android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause;//needs to be initialized
            PendingIntent play_pauseAction = null;
    
            //Build a new notification according to the current state of the MediaPlayer
            if (playbackStatus == PlaybackStatus.PLAYING) {
                notificationAction = android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause;
                //create the pause action
                play_pauseAction = playbackAction(1);
            } else if (playbackStatus == PlaybackStatus.PAUSED) {
                notificationAction = android.R.drawable.ic_media_play;
                //create the play action
                play_pauseAction = playbackAction(0);
            }
    
                fetchBitmapOfAlbum(); //replace with your own image
                String channelId = "";
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                    channelId = "APP_MUSIC";
                }
                // Create a new Notification
                NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                        // Hide the timestamp
                        .setShowWhen(false)
                        // Set the Notification style
                        .setStyle(new androidx.media.app.NotificationCompat.MediaStyle()
                                // Attach our MediaSession token
                                .setMediaSession(mediaSession.getSessionToken())
                                // Show our playback controls in the compat view
                                .setShowActionsInCompactView(0, 1, 2))
                        // Set the Notification color
                        .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this.getApplicationContext(), R.color.colorAccent))
                        // Set the large and small icons
                        .setLargeIcon(albumArtBitmap)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_notifications)
                        // Set Notification content information
                        .setContentText(activeAudio.getTrackName())
                        .setTicker(activeAudio.getAlbumName() + "-" + activeAudio.getTrackName())
                        .setOngoing(true)
                        .setContentTitle(activeAudio.getAlbumName())
                        .setContentInfo(activeAudio.getTrackName())
                        // Add playback actions
                        .addAction(notificationAction, "pause", play_pauseAction)
        
                ((NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)).notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.build());
        }
            
            
        private PendingIntent playbackAction(int actionNumber) {
            Intent playbackAction = new Intent(this, MediaPlayerService.class);
            switch (actionNumber) {
                case 0:
                    // Play
                    playbackAction.setAction(ACTION_PLAY);
                    return PendingIntent.getService(this, actionNumber, playbackAction, 0);
                case 1:
                    // Pause
                    playbackAction.setAction(ACTION_PAUSE);
                    return PendingIntent.getService(this, actionNumber, playbackAction, 0);
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return null;
        }
    
        private void removeNotification() {
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
        }
    
        private void handleIncomingActions(Intent playbackAction) {
            if (playbackAction == null || playbackAction.getAction() == null) return;
    
            String actionString = playbackAction.getAction();
            if (actionString.equalsIgnoreCase(ACTION_PLAY)) {
                transportControls.play();
            } else if (actionString.equalsIgnoreCase(ACTION_PAUSE)) {
                transportControls.pause();
            } 
        }        
        /**
         * Play new Audio
         */
        private BroadcastReceiver playNewAudio = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    
                //Get the new media index form SharedPreferences
                audioIndex = new StorageUtil(getApplicationContext()).loadAudioIndex();
                if (audioIndex != -1 && audioIndex < audioList.size()) {
                    //index is in a valid range
                    activeAudio = audioList.get(audioIndex);
                } else {
                    stopSelf();
                }
    
                //A PLAY_NEW_AUDIO action received
                //reset mediaPlayer to play the new Audio
                stopMedia();
                mediaPlayer.reset();
                initMediaPlayer();
                updateMetaData();
                buildNotification(PlaybackStatus.PLAYING);
            }
        };
    
        private void register_playNewAudio() {
            //Register playNewMedia receiver
            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(MainActivity.Broadcast_PLAY_NEW_AUDIO);
            registerReceiver(playNewAudio, filter);
        }
        
        public boolean isPlaying(){
            return mediaPlayer.isPlaying();
        }
    
        public void setShuffle(){
            if(shuffle) shuffle=false;
            else shuffle=true;
            StorageUtil storage = new StorageUtil(getApplicationContext());
            storage.storeShuffleRepeat("Shuffle", shuffle);
        }
    
        public void setRepeat(){
            if(repeat) repeat=false;
            else repeat=true;
            StorageUtil storage = new StorageUtil(getApplicationContext());
            storage.storeShuffleRepeat("Repeat", repeat);
        }
    }
```

> 2. Add the service to your manifest

```
<service android:name=".service.MediaPlayerService" />
```

> 3. Bind the service in MainActivity and declare methods to call the service

```
public class MainActivity {
    private MediaPlayerService player;
    boolean serviceBound = false;
    public static final String Broadcast_PLAY_NEW_AUDIO = "pkg_name.PlayNewAudio";
    //Binding this Client to the AudioPlayer Service
    private ServiceConnection serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            // We've bound to LocalService, cast the IBinder and get LocalService instance
            MediaPlayerService.LocalBinder binder = (MediaPlayerService.LocalBinder) service;
            player = binder.getService();
            serviceBound = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            serviceBound = false;
        }
    };

    // Call this method to play track
    public void playAudio(int audioIndex, ArrayList<PlayableTrack> updatedList) {
        //Check is service is active
        audioList = updatedList;
        if (!serviceBound) {    
            Intent playerIntent = new Intent(this, MediaPlayerService.class);
            startService(playerIntent);
            bindService(playerIntent, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        } else {   
            //Service is active
            //Send a broadcast to the service -> PLAY_NEW_AUDIO
            Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent(Broadcast_PLAY_NEW_AUDIO);
            sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
        }

    }
    // Additional methods for control
    public void start() {
        player.playMedia();
    }
    public void pause() {
        player.pauseMedia();
    }
    public boolean isPlaying() {
        if (player != null && serviceBound) {
            return player.isPlaying();
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

1- first add a music file in raw folder (in my case coffee.mp3)

2- create a class named BackgroundSoundService that extends Service:

```
public class BackgroundSoundService extends Service {

MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.coffee);
    mediaPlayer.setLooping(true); // Set looping
    mediaPlayer.setVolume(100, 100);
}
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    if (intent.getAction().equals("PLAY")) {
        if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying() == false) {
            mediaPlayer.start();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Music Is Playing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           
        }
    }
    if (intent.getAction().equals("STOP")) {
        this.stopService(intent);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Music Stopped",    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    
    return startId;
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    mediaPlayer.stop();
    mediaPlayer.release();
}
@Override
public void onLowMemory() {
}
}
```

do not forget to define this service in application tag of android manifest.xml:

```
<service android:name=".BackgroundSoundService" />
```

3- for play button in your activity use this code:

```
btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String action = "PLAY";
            Intent myService = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BackgroundSoundService.class);
            myService.setAction(action);
            startService(myService);
        }
    });
```

3- for stop button in your activity use this code:

```
btnStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String action = "STOP";
            Intent myService = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BackgroundSoundService.class);
            myService.setAction(action);
            startService(myService);
        }
    });
```

I have created a simple android app with two activity which play music in background service, the app will pause the music if app is not visible to the user (for example user pressed home button).
you can see it in my [github](https://github.com/farhad-kargaran/Play-Music-in-background-service-in-android) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can save a `Boolean` using `SharedPrefences` and restart the app every time settings was change And check the `Boolean` you saved in the setting.

```
If (your Boolean ==true) mediaplayer.start()
```