# Pause music to stay in the background but not when changing activity

Tags: android

I wonder if have any way to play a song and change to another activity and the music continues, but if you put the application in the background pause the music

Answer (score 0):

Look here [Play background music in all activities of Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27579765/play-background-music-in-all-activities-of-android-app)

Answer (score 0):

Make it simple !

Just try to start your MediaPlayer through a Service.
[Heres](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-music-player-on-android-song-playback--mobile-22778) a small example how to do it.

After you got this you can pause your Song through the Service maybe in the onDestroy method of your Activity.

Hopes this helps !